# New to Spring - when/where application context is instantiation all the beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I got this code from [mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/)

```
ApplicationContext context = 
      new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"Spring-Customer.xml"});

    CustomerService cust = (CustomerService)context.getBean("customerService");
```

In the above code, when/where the `ApplicationContext` is instantiating the bean `customerService` which configured in file `Spring-Customer.xml` like this.

```
<bean id="customerService" class="com.mkyong.customer.services.CustomerService">
    <property name="customerDAO" ref="customerDAO" />
</bean>
```

Simply when/where the `new CustomerService()` will get happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to answer to your question is to add a break point in the constructor of a bean and see what happens when debugging.

I've added the break point in a radom class called `CrawlerManager` from some random java app.

Here is the bean definition:

```
<bean id="crawlerManager" class="ro.geopatani.crawlers.CrawlerManager"/>
```

Here is what I got:

[image: debug frames]

1. `ApplicationContext` instantiation in main method as follows:

   ```
   public static void main (String ... args){
       ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");    }
   ```
2. Because the default bean scope in spring is `singleton` this is the point where the instantion of singleton beans start.

The following method is invoked with the name of the bean `CrawlerManager`

```
public Object getBean(String name) throws BeansException {
            return doGetBean(name, null, null, false);
}
```

3. `Class.newInstance()` is called and the constructor of the `CrawlerManager` gets triggered.

What is also important to mention that the method `AbstractApplicationContext.refresh()` is the place where all the bean definitions are loaded from `spring.xml` file.

Here is how that happens exactly:
[image: debug frames-load beans]

Here is the exact code for the refresh method, where you can see the call to `obtainFreshBeanFactory()`:

```
    public void refresh() throws BeansException, IllegalStateException {
    synchronized (this.startupShutdownMonitor) {
        // Prepare this context for refreshing.
        prepareRefresh();

        // Tell the subclass to refresh the internal bean factory.
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = obtainFreshBeanFactory();

        // Prepare the bean factory for use in this context.
        prepareBeanFactory(beanFactory);

        try {
            // Allows post-processing of the bean factory in context subclasses.
            postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);

            // Invoke factory processors registered as beans in the context.
            invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(beanFactory);

            // Register bean processors that intercept bean creation.
            registerBeanPostProcessors(beanFactory);

            // Initialize message source for this context.
            initMessageSource();

            // Initialize event multicaster for this context.
            initApplicationEventMulticaster();

            // Initialize other special beans in specific context subclasses.
            onRefresh();

            // Check for listener beans and register them.
            registerListeners();

            // Instantiate all remaining (non-lazy-init) singletons.
            finishBeanFactoryInitialization(beanFactory);

            // Last step: publish corresponding event.
            finishRefresh();
        }

        catch (BeansException ex) {
            // Destroy already created singletons to avoid dangling resources.
            destroyBeans();

            // Reset 'active' flag.
            cancelRefresh(ex);

            // Propagate exception to caller.
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, adds value and can able to understand, what is happening behind

Answer (score 0):

In Spring, every singleton beans are eagerly initialized. So when you load your context i.e. in your case when you call `..new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"Spring-Customer.xml"});` at that time your customer service bean will be created.

If you want to avoid that, you could use attribute like `lazy-init="true"` in your spring config xml.

Comment: Yes, I just want to understand, what is happening behind the hood. When and where it get `initialized`?

Comment: What do you understand from my answer then when you say `Yes, I got just want to understand` Behind the scene it will call `new CustomerService()` and then it will call `setCustomerDAO(..)` on same bean that it initiated while creating application context,

Comment: So you saying that, the class `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` will contain the code, that will create `new CustomerService()` am I right?

Comment: It wont have code. It will read your xml and will find out how to create your beans, will figure out dependencies and then using reflection will start creating beans.

Comment: If you don't mind, from http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/4.1.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java#ClassPathXmlApplicationContext I couldn't able to understand how ClassPathXmlApplicationContext is asking `reflections` to create the bean

Comment: You need to then debug the whole flow or run you code with logging framework in debug mode and see what's going on behind the scene..